# wso2 api-manager configurations for cluster environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

### Environment

So I have a Clustered environment with an API Manager and two gateway workers (the gateways are on a load balancer) and two Identity Servers as Key Managers (Load Balancer).

I get confused when it comes to configuring the below code.

```
            <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
            <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
            <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
            <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
            <ServerURL>https://gatemgrdev.byui.edu/services/</ServerURL>
                    <!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
            <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
            <!-- Admin password for the API gateway.-->
            <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
            <!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.-->
            <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
        </Environment>
    </Environments>
</APIGateway>
```

In my Identity Servers I usually point the Server URL to my API Manager. Like so

```
<ServerURL>https://apimgr.org/services/</ServerURL>
```

In my API Manager I usually change the configs to this

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://gateworker.org,https://gateworker.org</GatewayEndpoint>
```

So how should I configure the gateway workers? Do I have to do anything to them? Also, I'm I configuring the two above correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the gateway configurations from [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Clustering+the+API+Manager#ClusteringtheAPIManager-ConfiguringtheGateway

Thanks
Isura.